# Primitive to class equals

Tags: typescript

I am running into a problem here:
This works in JavaScript

```
class X { valueOf() { return "."; } }

new X() == "." -> true
```

I want the same thing in TypeScript:

```
class QueryString extends QueryType {
  startsWith(value: string | QueryString): boolean { ... }
  someMethodThatIsDefenetlyNotInTheStringInterface(): boolean { ... }

  valueOf(): string { ... }
}

class Car {
  name: QueryString;
}

db.cars.find(c => c.name == "test");
```

This throws an error, in the comparison because `QueryString` and `string` do not overlap (because of the `someMethodThatIsDefenetlyNotInTheStringInterface`-Method).
Sure, I could do this:

```
class Car {
  name: QueryString & string;
}
```

But this would expose methods from the string interface which don't want to implement in the QueryString class (for example, i don't want to have the deprecated, HTML-generating functions like `fontcolor`).

How can I make comparisons possible, without exposing/implementing the complete string interface?

The comparison should be a simple as possible, as it is used often (for example: making it `c.name.valueOf() == "test"` works, but would make it look ugly). The `QueryString` class can be easily changed, as well as the `Car`-Class, as it will be automatically generated by the ORM (https://npmjs.org/vlquery).

Thank you in advance! <3

Comment: You probably shouldn't be relying on implicit type conversion. It's easy to introduce a small error that is hard to spot and debug. Also, the semantics around the conversion can be quite complex. I'd stick to being explicit - it's easier to write and maintain. It also helps because TS doesn't freak out over it.

Comment: Yeah, from [microsoft/TypeScript#25642](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25642) you'll probably need to do something yourself to work around it; the best would be something explicit like `c.name.valueOf() == "test"`. It may be "ugly" but at least it is obvious what's happening to everyone including the ocmpiler